# Sending MQTT commands with QOS1 via GCP Cloud IOT

Tags: mqtt, google-cloud-iot

We are currently trying to communicate with Edge devices using MQTT. We use the config topic for defining the algorithms to use, the version of software and so on.

We would like to use **commands** for sending "calculation results" back to the devices. We have to send it from the cloud towards the devices since multiple devices are working together on this.

This state is important for the device to visualise the correct state and therefor we would like to have QOS1 for these commands.
According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands#commands_compared_to_configurations) this should be possible but I can't find out how to do this.

We are using the API's for managing these config and commands.

Comment: QOS is just one of the fields in an MQTT packet.  What software are you using to Publish the "calculation results"  from?  ...there should be an option to set QOS.  If you are using custom code, then the programming language MQTT module should have an option for setting QOS.

Comment: I'm using the SDK of gcp iot. Behind the scenes this is using HTTP to send a command via the API op IOT core.

Comment: I would love to help if provide which language are you using. Every example uses eclipse paho client so library is similar in every language (Java, Go, Python...)

Comment: I'm using Java for this with the [gcp IOT SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/java-iot). Behind the scenes it is not using Paho but direct HTTP API's. 
In the HTTP API's I have not found any way of passing the QOS level.